# Run Cron Jobs Orderly with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to run scheduled cron jobs orderly in Spring MVC like one of them finish then the next cron is going to start.

```
    //cron1
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 * * * ?")
    public void test1(){
       ....
    }
    //cron2
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 * * * ?")
    public void test2(){
       ....
    }
```

I want to run test1 then test2. On the other hand, this two methods are from different classes.

And figure that, you have more than 2 methods have same cron time. In that case, i cannot call all scheduled methods under "one" same cron scheduled method.

Can anyone help.
thanks

Comment: Have **one** cron job that consists of `test1(); test2();`. Otherwise you'll need to use something more advanced like [Quartz](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) - with one job triggering the next.

Comment: Not overly helpful - although you edited early. You need to make clear precisely what you want answered, whether you have a specific example of a more complex use case. You'll have to use Quartz if you have more complex task throws...